# Invariant definition of graded Poisson bracket

Tags: supermanifolds, differential-graded-lie-algebras

Given a graded manifold with symplectic form $\omega$ of degree $n$, I have seen two expressions for the corresponding Poisson bracket of degree $-n$. Cattaneo-Fiorenza-Longoni, http://www.math.uzh.ch/fileadmin/math/preprints/15-05.pdf in section 2.7, give $$\lbrace f,g \rbrace=\iota_{X_{f}}\iota_{X_{g}} \omega,$$ while Cattaneo-Schatz, arXiv:1011.3401 in example 4.9, give
$$\lbrace f,g \rbrace=(-1)^{|f|+1}X_{f}(g).$$

It seems to me that it is the latter that gives the proper graded anticommutativity so that the Poisson bracket is a Lie bracket of degree $-n$.

Is one of the two definitions mistaken or is it a matter of differing conventions?

Answer (score 2):

If one adopts the convention that the Hamiltonian vector field $X_h$ is defined by the equation $\iota_{X_h}\omega=dh$ (as both Cattaneo-Fiorenza-Longoni and Cattaneo-Schaetz do), and that $\iota_X(df)=X(f)$, then yes, there is a missing $(-1)^{|f|+1}$ factor in front of the formula in Cattaneo-Fiorenza-Longoni. But I can imagine other graded symplectic geometry sign conventions in which $\{f,g\}=\iota_{X_f}\iota_{X_g}\omega$ is the correct formula. For instance, in ordinary symplectic geometry, it is customary to define Hamiltonian vector fields by the equation $\iota_{X_h}\omega+dh=0$ rather than by $\iota_{X_h}\omega=dh$, and with this convetion one has $\iota_{X_f}\iota_{X_g}\omega=-X_f(g)$ with no need of additional sign corrections.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a reason for the customary definition of Hamiltonian vector field? Does this have something to do with the interpretation of $h$ as energy, which should be positive?

Comment: Indeed that could be a reason, but I have to admit not be expert at all on motivations from classical mechanics. From a purely mathematical point of view, using the defining equation `$\iota_{X_h}\omega+dh=0$` one has `$X_{\{f,g\}}=[X_f,X_g]$` and so mapping a smooth function to its Hamiltonian vector field is a Lie algebra homomorphism from the Poisson algebra of the symplectic manifold to the Lie algebra of vector fields, rather than a Lie algebra antihomomorphism as is the case using `$\iota_{X_h}\omega=dh$`.

Comment: This comes from stating Hamilton's equations in the standard form for which rate-of-change-of-position-and-momentum is on one side of the equation and derivatives-of-the-Hamiltonian is on the other. Signs are inserted to make this come out right. Every since Newton physicists usually state their equations of motion this way (rate of change = source of rate of change) -- unless they are Richard Feynman and are joking around, then they may bring each and everything to the left and have a zero on the right.

Comment: @domenico. I think your comment about the Lie algebra homomorphism is worth adding to your answer.


Comment: @Urs. I remember hearing about Feynman's joke, but I don't remember it well enough to find it funny. Could you refresh my memory?

Comment: A decent discussion of this comment of Feynman's happens to be in item 7 here: http://www.wired.co.uk/magazine/archive/2012/05/start/want-to-work-at-google 

(By the way, I am not implying anything about the above discussion. I was just in the kind of mood to recall this "joke". In particular Domenico's reply is excellent. Also, I'd dare say that Feynman's point is to be taken with grains of salt. For instance, that most equations of motion in physics are equivalent to delta S = 0 for suitable functional S, once you reorganize them a bit, is of genuine importance.)


Comment: @domenico.  Upon further reflection, I don't see why in ordinary symplectic geometry that the convention, it seems to me that $\iota_{X_{h}}\omega=dh$ is the convention so that the definition $\{f,g\}=\iota_{X_{f}}\iota_{X_{g}}\omega$ gives a Lie algebra homomorphism. Indeed, since $\iota_{[X,Y]}=[L_{X},\iota_{Y}]$ for any two vector fields $X,Y$, we have `$\iota_{[X_{f},X_{g}]}=L_{X_{f}}\iota_{X_{g}}\omega=d(\iota_{X_{f}}\iota_{X_{g}} \omega)=d(\lbrace f,g \rbrace)$`.

Comment: Can't edit comments. I meant, upon further reflection, it seems to me that. Ignore `I don't see why... that the convention'. Also, note that with the convention $\iota_{X_{h}} \omega+dh=0$, you would get a Lie algebra homomorphism from defining $\lbrace f, g \rbrace=\iota_{X_{g}}\iota_{X_{f}}\omega$. 

Comment: Comparing Arnold and Abraham-Marsden-Ratiu, it seems that part of the confusion comes from whether you take $\omega$ to be $position \wedge momentum$ or $momentum \wedge position$. Arnold uses the latter and works with $\iota_{X_{h}}\omega+dh=0$, so far as I can tell, and defines $\lbrace f,h \rbrace=X_{h}(f)$. And he gets a Lie algebra homomorphism. 